# Is there a way to make my basemap light in google map api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The base-map in google is very heavy as it is having all the layers.
I want to make it lightweight by clearing some layers while rendering so that it loads quickly and also when I add objects to the map like markers or line it is clearly visible. I have a use case where the client dos not need a detailed map as it is of less importance. The client wants the objects to be nice and clear.

I tried to get rid of some layers by switching them off but the changes are not getting reflected.

```
function initialize()
{

  var roadAtlasStyles = [
                         {
                           featureType: 'road.highway',
                           elementType: 'geometry',
                           stylers: [
                             { visibility: 'on' }
                           ]
                         },{
                           featureType: 'road.arterial',
                           elementType: 'all',
                           stylers: [
                                     { visibility: 'on' }
                                   ]
                         },{
                           featureType: 'road.local',
                           elementType: 'all',
                           stylers: [
                                     { visibility: 'off' }
                                   ]
                         },{
                           featureType: 'water',
                           elementType: 'geometry',
                           stylers: [
                                     { visibility: 'on' }
                                   ]
                         },{
                           featureType: 'road.highway',
                           elementType: 'labels',
                           stylers: [
                                     { visibility: 'on' }
                                   ]
                         },
                         {
                               featureType: 'poi',
                               elementType: 'labels',
                               stylers: [
                                         { visibility: 'off' }
                                       ]
                          },{
                           featureType: 'administrative',
                           elementType: 'labels',
                           stylers: [
                                     { visibility: 'on' }
                                   ]
                         },{
                           featureType: 'transit.station.rail',
                           elementType: 'geometry',
                           stylers: [
                                     { visibility: 'off' }
                                   ]
                         }
                       ];



                    var mapOptions ={
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(28.6139,77.2090),
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'usroadatlas']
                      },
                    streetViewControl: true,
                    panControl: false,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
                    },
                    zoom:16
                };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);    
        var styledMapOptions = { name: 'Netran' };

        var usRoadMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
          roadAtlasStyles, styledMapOptions);

          map.mapTypes.set('usroadatlas', usRoadMapType);             

         var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
         var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);

         homeControlDiv.index = 1;
         map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);

     }
```

Comment: I recommend playing around with the Maps Platform Styling Wizard https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: Thanks Evan !!! That was the exact thing I was looking for. Just set your style and get the code for it.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! :) I'm posting this as my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend playing around with the [Maps Platform Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). It allows you to quickly customize a map as desired and then generate a JSON styling object.